# How to create a custom metric using Sonar API

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I am creating a plugin for Sonar and I need to create a custom metric since there are no core metrics within Sonar API that fulfill my needs.

I need to be able to display this metric on the dashboard.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I was also searching for this. But bumped into a thread and it seems custom metrics is deprecated. More details here: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/monitoring-custom-metrics-of-a-project/12568/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find examples in the Community plugins for SonarQube project.

For instance, the Sonar Artifact Size Plugin defines some additional metrics. You can see the code in https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-artifact-size/tree/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/artifactsize

Comment: Now this link is broken -_-